# The list with most elements

Tags: list, dictionary, python

I have a list with dictionary as elements. Each dictionary has an entry called type. The type field represents a list. What is the simplest/pythonic way of obtaining the list with the most elements?

```
programmes_by_type = []
programmes_by_type.append({'type' : [1, 2, 3]})
programmes_by_type.append({'type' : [2, 5]})
programmes_by_type.append({'type' : [3]})
programmes_by_type.append({'type' : [11, 2, 6, 7]})
```

Given the previous example it should return the `[11, 2, 6, 7]` list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
max([option['type'] for option in programmes_by_type], key=len)
```

Comment: (+1) for `max(..., key=...)`. It may be worth noting that this requires Python 2.5.

Comment: It is the right answer. I will answer in a short time. One last thing, how would you modify it if the type entry would be a dictionary containing a type_list entry and I would need the type_list list with most elements?

Comment: `max(programmes_by_type, key=lambda v: len(v['type']))` would return the dict rather than the list

Answer (score 0):

```
max_length = 0
type_list = None

for el in programmes_by_type:
    if len(el) > max_length:
        max_length = len(el)
        type_list = el['type']
```

`type_list` now contains the biggest list.

Comment: Nitpick: There's no `Null` in Python, just `None`.